# Parser error on redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I get a parser error when running my code and have checked references but everything seems in place.The error occurs when on a redirect from a page The error occurs on line 1.

```
<%@ Page Title="CreateUser" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CreateUser.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="ICSWebPortal.Portal.Pages.User.CreateUser" PageName="Create User" PageDescription="Details of user" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Main.Master" %>
```

This is my redirect function on another page

```
function CreateNewUser()
{
    window.location = "<% = GetHost() %>/User/Create/"
}
```

Comment: What exact error you get and what is the result URL?

Comment: 'ICSWebPortal.Portal.Pages.User.CreateUser' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'. and http://localhost:24063/User/Create/

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = "<%= GetHost() %>/User/Create/";
```

OR

```
window.location = "<%# GetHost() %>/User/Create/";
```

OR

```
window.location = "<%: GetHost() %>/User/Create/";
```

Either one of them should work.